# Select a page element with a stored value

Tags: python, selenium

Issue: Unable to select a page element, using a stored value.

Situation: I need to open a page, using the find.element(By.ID, "element", value=storedvalue).click() According to documents, I should be able to do this. Maybe I am reading it wrong? I get a TypeError, meaning I am using the function wrong. o.O

http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html

Step through code:

Store the value of `testingNum`

Go to another page where the selection has been saved

Verify the value of `myvalue` is on the current page

Select the page element `pick_id` that has `myvalue` as it's actual value (see HTML)

HTML:

```
<li id="pick_id" value="261">261</li>
```

Test Code Snippet:

```
    myvalue = driver.find_element_by_id("testingNum").get_attribute("value")
    driver.find_element_by_id("verify_btn").click()
    self.assertTrue(self.is_text_present(myvalue))
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "pick_id", value=myvalue).click()
```

Error: `TypeError: find_element() got multiple values for keyword argument 'value'`

Answer (score 1):

you are getting a TypeError because you are calling `find_element` wrong.

incorrect:

```
driver.find_element(By.ID, "pick_id", value=myvalue)
```

`find_element` takes 2 keyword arguments, `by`, and `value`.

you are passing 2 positional arguments, and then a keyword argument.  the 2nd positional argument is interpreted as `value`.  when you then pass the keyword argument `value=` you get a Type error since you defined multiple values for "value"

Comment: Alright. I thought this would be correct now, still getting the TypeError though: `driver.find_element(By.ID, "pick_id", myvalue).click()` and tried `driver.find_element(By.ID, "pick_id", myvalue)` and get, `TypeError: find_element() takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)`

Comment: Corey, how would you write out this statement so you can `click()` this page element?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to match on two attributes - `id` and `value` of the `li` element.

As @Corey says, you are calling find_element() wrong; it takes 2 keyword arguments - the first argument specifies how (ID , Name, xpath, css etc), and the second specifies the filter `value`.

Use xpath when you want to match on more than one attribute:

```
driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//li[@id='pick_id' and @value='" + myvalue+ "']")
```

Comment: Thanks, Faiz. However, I added the .click() arg on the end. It does not fail but also does not handle the click event.

Comment: Does the `find_element()` call find the correct `li` element ? Ensure that the element is properly identified before calling click  - assign the element to a variable to check. Might have to try different xpath queries,though this is pretty straightforward. You can also try to click using [action chains](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html).